# CSS3 div and last-child - how aright?

Tags: css, html, css-selectors

CODE:

```
<div class="AllDiv">
    <div class="LeftDiv">
        <div class="LeftDiv2">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="Photo"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="News">
        .....
    </div>
</div>

<div class="AllDiv">
    <div class="LeftDiv">
        <div class="LeftDiv2">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="Photo"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="News">
        .....
    </div>
</div>

<div class="AllDiv">
    <div class="LeftDiv">
        <div class="LeftDiv2">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="Photo"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="News">
        .....
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like make that last div, `LeftDiv`, get CSS `display:none`.

For it I use code: `div.AllDiv .LeftDiv .LeftDiv2:last-child{display:none;}`, but it is not working.

Also i try use `i use`div.AllDiv:last-child div.LeftDiv .LeftDiv2{display:none;}`, but it not work` too.

Tell me please where error and how write it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LeftDiv2 is the first child if it's parent element, not the last child. However, you don't need the last child class at all. just remove `:last-child`. If you really wanted to select it using the pseudo class you would want `:first-child` in your current markup.